# Getting Error only in IE10 for Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net

I am getting error only in IE10 browser.
Please see the Error log:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
```

By looking at the log,it seems that there is conversion problem only in IE10.
In other browsers this issue is not reproducible.

Could you please interpret what could be the problem?

Comment: When does this error occur? Is it when you click an image button, or every time you load the page or...what?

Answer (score 4):

You need a hotfix from Microsoft, to be deployed on the server:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Basically, .net detects the client browser using the user agent sent by the client to the server, but .net4 doesn't recognise IE10's string.
I found details here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx