# Ajax toolkit not working properly in IE 10

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a website in which I have used Asp.net AjaxToolkit modal popup element.

It worked fine on every browser, but recently I tested it on Internet Explorer 10 (on windows 7 platform), and discovered a problem.

When I open a modal popup, the popup content is not loading and a message box is appearing with an error like this:

> "Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input
>   string was not in a correct format."

Anyone heard about this error?

What is going wrong, what kind of "Input string" I was prompted about?

Write an answer please, if you know what the problem is.

Comment: Looks like the server code of your application threw an exception with the message "Input string was not in a correct format": probably a `FormatException`, possibly thrown by a `Parse` method.  Try debugging the server code with IE10.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416338/getting-error-only-in-ie10-for-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format

Answer (score 0):

There is a known problem with ASP.NET and IE10. See Scott Hanselman's blog article about this.

[ASP.NET fails to Detect IE10 ...](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

The quickest solution from this Blog article is to use NuGet to add updated App_Browser files to your project. The Blog includes additional options, and is worth a read.